# ¿Se puede cambiar el contenido de un TextView en un MainActivity desde una clase en Java?

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

Acabo de comenzar en esto de la programación en Android hace un par de meses y ahora mismo estoy desarrollando una aplicación muy simple pero me causa mucha ilusión tratar de hacer que funcione :D.

Yendo al grano, mi pregunta se encuentra en el título. Les muestro lo que estoy intentando hacer a continuación...

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mainActivityTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainActivityTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mainActivityTextView.setText("I am void!");

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass("Hello World!");
            }
        });       
    }

    public void changeMainActivityTextView(String newText) {
        mainActivityTextView.setText(newText);
    }
}
```

OtherClass.java:

```
public class OtherClass {
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public OtherClass(String newText) {
        mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.changeMainActivityTextView(newText):
    }
}
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es tratar de cambiar el contenido de un TextView del MainActivity desde otra clase haciendo uso de un botón. Al presionar el botón del MainActivity este llama a la función "OtherClass" quien recibe un parámetro de tipo String, y dentro de su constructor llama al método "changeMainActivityTextView" enviando el parámetro recibido. Pero esta lógica da un error al presionar el botón. Este error es el que se lanza: "*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference*"
Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo? De antemano muchas Gracias! :D

Comment: donde declaras el string newText?

Comment: No lo hago. Simplemente se lo paso sin declarar. Ocurre justo en evento del botón.

Comment: Pero dónde le asignas el valor?

Comment: **OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass("Hello World!")**; En esa línea estoy enviando el "Hello World!" pero sin haberlo declarado antes como una String. Te refieres a eso verdad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrás que sacar el dato desde tu clase principal.
Cuando haces esto:

```
public class OtherClass {
private MainActivity mainActivity;

public OtherClass(String newText) {
    mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.changeMainActivityTextView(newText):
    }
}
```

Manda un error pues estás creando un nuevo activity, no el que estás usando, ahí mismo lo dice: "mainActivity = new ..."
Para poder sacarlo desde tu clase principal tendrás que declarar una variable de tipo global y pública en tu clase "otherClass"

```
public class OtherClass {

//Variable global uwu    
public String texto; 

public OtherClass(String newText) {
         this.texto = newText; 
    }
}
```

De esa forma ya le habremos dado un valor por medio de un parámetro a la variable "texto", después, tendrás que sacar esa variable desde tu clase principal de la siguiente manera:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass("Hello World!");

            //Aquí saca la variable de la clase otherClass y la introduce en donde sea que la estás poniendo
            mainActivityTextView.setText(otherClass.texto);
        }
    });
```

Un error común es pensar que puedes controlar una clase desde otra clase que ha sido invocada por la primer clase.

Comment: Miguel Cliché muchas gracias por tu comentario. Me has echo entender de un error que estoy cometiendo de forma muy habitual. En serio muchas gracias. Justo mientras estaba apunto de hacer lo que has dicho se me ocurrió cambiar la variable "private TextView mainActivityTextView;" a "private static TextView mainActivityTextView;" y en el onCreate del MainActivity le asigne la ID correspondiente. Echo los cambios decidí correr la aplicación en mi Móvil y funciona correctamente. Lo que acabo de hacer es válido? Gracias :D

Comment: Realmente no lo sé, en caso de trabajar con más gente supongo que importaría saber si eso es correcto o no hacerlo, pero supongo que si lo estás haciendo solo no importa mientras tú lo entiendas, no soy experto, pero me alegra que te funcione uwu